# What is the javascript equivalent for jQuery(".myContent").hide()statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the javascript equivalent for the jQuery hide(). What will be the javascript equivalent for the below statement

```
jQuery(".myContent").hide()
```

Answer (score 2):

On all modern browsers, and also IE8, you can do it with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), which you frequently find in conjunction with `Array.prototype.forEach` or `Array.prototype.slice`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".myContent"), function(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
});
```

It's nearly universally supported, *slightly* more so than `getElementsByClassName`, which isn't supported by IE8. (The `Array.prototype.forEach.call` part is to give us a convenient way to loop over the results.)

On properly modern browsers (or with a shim), you can combine it with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".myContent")).forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
});
```

Or technically you can do it like this:

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".myContent"), function(el) {
        el.style.display = "none";
    });

...since `Array.from` accepts a mapping function.

In either case, you'd probably want to give yourself a wrapper function for brevity.

---

If you only need to hide the *first* element with that class, it's `querySelector`:

```
// Assumes there *will* be a match, throws error if not
document.querySelector(".myContent").style.display = "none";
```

or

```
// Doesn't make that assumption
var el = document.querySelector(".myContent");
if (el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('myContent');
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
  x[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Hides everything with that class, no jQuery.